# What kind of other light sources can disturb the detection of LASER

Tags: visible-light, laser

My project objective is to detect different lasers , for example

*Laser Range Finder*: `pulse width` 10ns and `repetition rate` is 1Hz-1KHz

*Laser Target Designator*: `pulse width` 100ns and `repetition rate` is <50Khz

at this point of time i feel , only the pulse detection is crucial, but i want to know what other sources can fall and disturb the laser detection

in this angle i found other sources to be

*non-coherent sources like flash lamp, welders and reflected beams*

i feel flash lamp and welders are slowly varying light sources ,

*such slow sources can be filtered out using a High pass filter*

but what other sources can enter in to this region and make the detection of laser very difficult ?

> But to how to handle High Intensity Light overlapping with pulsed
>   laser ?

EDIT1: anyway a wavelength optical filter of band 500-1800nm is placed

PS:This is more physics question than a signal processing one i feel ! because i want to know the sources of disturbance here

Comment: Generally, you won't be able to do better than with a narrow (10nm) optical bandpass. If your laser comes from a known direction, I would definitely include a narrow angular filter. The pulse structure should be exploited with a boxcar integrator. Taken together you should be able to get over 120-150dB of suppression of interfering white light. If you have an active laser interference source, that's another problem altogether, though.

Comment: isnt a boxcar integrator a bulky set up ?

Comment: Not really, it's basically a PLL and sampling switch followed by an integrator. Depending on the details it could be as few as half a dozen packages of off-the-shelf electronics. If you know the timing of the laser pulses and you can do without the PLL, it's even less.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is cover your detector with an optical filter that only allows through light with the same wavelength as the laser you are looking for.

Comment: That's a bit vague, don't you think?  (bandwidth, eg)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Not at all. It is very precise and is the first thing any engineer would think of. There is an entire industry producing optical filters for various purposes, including laser filters that both block selected wavelength or transmit them. http://www.omegafilters.com/applications/laser-filters/

Comment: yeah its there i am putting a optical filter of band 500-1800nm wavelength

Comment: @kakeh That lets just about anything through - you might as well use a sheet of glass. Get one specified for the laser wavelength